# discord.js and whether I need 2 bot.logins?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been working on a discord bot and I require a script from `index.js` but I am wondering if I should do `bot.login` at the bottom of `cmdFunctions.js` too?

[image: explorer]

index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const cmdFunctions = require('./cmdFunctions.js');
const config = require("./config.json");

var prefix = '>';
bot.on('ready', msg=>{
    console.log('This bot is online');
})
bot.on('message', msg =>{
    if (!msg.content.slice(0,1) == " "){
        var content = msg.content;
        msgArray = content.split(" ");
        msgPrefix = msgArray[0].slice(0,1);
        msgCMD = msgArray[0].slice(1);
        if (msg.author.bot === false && msgPrefix == config.prefix && cmdFunctions[msgCMD]) {
            cmdFunctions[msgCMD](content.substring(content.indexOf(' ')+1), msg);
        }
    }
})
bot.login(config.token);
```

cmdFunctions.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const cmdFunctions = require('./cmdFunctions.js');
const config = require("./config.json");
module.exports = {
    reactionRoleGroups: function(vars, msg) {
        bot.on("messageReactionAdd", (messageReaction, user) =>{
            console.log(":L");
            if (true){
                RRGM.edit("Thanks!")
            }
        })
        varsSplit = vars.split(config.variableSeperator);
        var Emojis = varsSplit[0];
        if (Emojis) {
            var EmojisSeperated = Emojis.split(",");
            var RRGM = msg.channel.send("You are setting up a RR Group") //.send("hello /n :)")
        }
    }
}
```

This is my post so tell me if I need anything else. :)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, no need to. You only need to login at the end of the main script, unless you're initializing an entirely different application with a different token from the second script.